# Проблема со связанными списками в Yii2

Tags: yii2, двусвязный-список

Здравствуйте, делаю связанные списки выбора региона и города в Yii2

View
        //выбор региона

```
    $items = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Region::find()->all(), 'id', 'name');
    echo $forms->field($models, 'obl')->widget(kartik\select2\Select2::className(),[
    'data' => $items,
    'options' => ['onchange' => '$.post( "'. yii\helpers\Url::toRoute('site/lists?id=').'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
     $( "select#name" ).html( data );}); '],
```

//выбор города

```
    $item = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\City::find()->all(), 'id', 'name');
    echo $forms->field($models, 'city')->widget(kartik\select2   \Select2::className(),[
   'data' => $item,
   'options' => ['id' => 'name'],
```

Контроллер

public function actionLists($id){

```
    $countCity = \app\models\City::find()
            ->where(['region_id'=>$id])
            ->count();
    $cityes = \app\models\City::find()
            ->where(['region_id'=>$id])
            ->all();
    if($countCity>0){
        foreach ($cityes as $city){
            echo "<option value='".$city->id."'>".$city->name."</options>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<options></options>";
    }
```

Суть проблемы заключается в том, что на странице у меня две разные формы в которых встречаются эти списки, и если в первой форме все работает как надо, то во второй форме, поле выбора города не отображается вовсе. Если из выбора города убрать 'id' => 'name', то поле становится видимым, но разумеется связь со списком регионов пропадает. Есть ли возможность как-нибудь заставить вторую пару регионов и городов работать не прибегая к сторонним расширениям?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

id это уникальное поле и нельзя назначать один id двум разным элементам на одной странице. Надо сделать что бы в первом случае id было допустим "name-1" а во втором "name-2"